# xcode: ERROR: ibtool failed with exception: Unexpected SDK identifier macosx10.6

Tags: ios4

I am trying to build an older MAC project on Xcode. When i try to build the same i come across the following error. I am not able to get the correct resolution for this.

ERROR: ibtool failed with exception: Unexpected SDK identifier macosx10.6

In my xcode project targets i have set my BASE SDK as MACOSx10.6 and in provisioning profiles i have made don't sign over there.

Still i am getting this issue.

Can you let me know the solution for this.

thanks and Regards

Comment: Are you building for iPhone or for Mac OS X? I'm confused from your description.

Comment: Its a program i am building for iPhone and MAC both. when i run the same for the iphone version 4.2 it runs where as when i want to build the same for the MAC than i am selecting the above configuration mentioned. 
So could you help me out of this .

thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to Xcode installation problems. You should be abel to fix this by reinstalling Xcode.

Before doing that, you can try changing "Base SDK" from project info window which can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Am sure the issue must have come after updating the XCode. If so, then try reverting it back to the older version or try looking for info.plist file because at times when you update the XCode, the info.plist file gets deleted. Hope this resolves your error.